# checksum calculation

Tags: c++, reverse-engineering, checksum, crc

To calculate CRC I found a piece of code but I am not understanding the concept.
Here is the code:

```
count =128 and ptr=some value;
```

`calcrc(unsigned char *ptr, int count)
{
    unsigned short  crc;
    unsigned char i;

    crc = 0;

    while (--count >= 0)
    {
        crc = crc ^ (unsigned short)*ptr++ << 8;
        i = 8;
        do
        {
            if (crc & 0x8000)
                crc = crc << 1 ^ 0x1021;
            else
                crc = crc << 1;
        } while(--i);
    }
    return (crc);
}`

Please any body explain and tell me the logic.

Comment: I suggest you be more specific about what you don't understand. Is it the syntax or semantics of the algorithm, something else???

Answer (score 4):

This looks like a [CRC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_redundancy_check) (specifically it looks like CRC-16-CCITT, used by things like 802.15.4, X.25, V.41, CDMA, Bluetooth, XMODEM, HDLC, PPP and IrDA). You might want to read up on the CRC theory on the linked-to Wikipedia page, to gain some more insight. Or you can view this as a "black box" that just solves the problem of computing a checksum.

Answer (score 3):

You will probably need to know that in C, the ^ operator is a bitwise XOR [operator](http://www.cppreference.com/wiki/operator_precedence) and the << operator is the left shift operator (equivalent to multiplication by 2 to the power of the number on the right of the operator). Also the crc & 0x8000 expression is testing for the most significant bit set of the variable crc.
This will help you to work out a low level explanation of what is occurring when this runs, for a high level explanation of what a CRC is and why you might need it, read the [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_redundancy_check) or [How Stuff Works](http://computer.howstuffworks.com/encryption7.htm).

Answer (score 3):

One famous text on CRCs is ["A Painless Guide to CRC Error Detection Algorithms"](http://www.ross.net/crc/crcpaper.html) by Ross Williams. It takes some time to absorb but it's pretty thorough.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at my answer to 
[How could I guess a checksum algorithm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/149617/how-could-i-guess-a-checksum-algorithm/158693#158693)